# Referencing Matrix (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I have a matrix (5x5) with values in them for example:

> Matrix (1,1) Value: 'a'
>
> Matrix (1, 2) Value: 'b'
>
> Matrix (2, 1) Value: 'c'

how would I be able to find the letter 'a' in that matrix and have it output the coordinates?

ie

> user inputs 'b'
>
> [searches for 'b' in table]
>
> output (1,2)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To LengthOfMatrix - 1
  For y As Integer = 0 To HeightOfMatrix - 1
    If Matrix(i, y) = "a" Then Console.Write(i & " " & y & vbCrLf)
  Next
Next
```

Asuming that you declared Matrix as:

```
Dim Matrix As Char(,) = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}}
```

And LengthOfMatrix And HeightOfMatrix should be the dimentions of your matrix. They could be switched to something more dynamic like:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Matrix.GetLength(0) - 1 'Get's the length of the first dimension
  For y As Integer = 0 To Matrix.GetLength(1) - 1 'Get's the length of the second dimension
    If Matrix(i, y) = "a" Then Console.Write(i & " " & y & vbCrLf)
  Next
Next
```

In a short description, all that this loop does is it goes through all of the elements of the matrix and outputs the coordinates of every element that matches a certain criteria (In this case - equals to 'a').

---

Note: In most programming languages array's indexes begin from 0, so the first element in your matrix will be at coords (0,0).

Comment: just wondering... how would this work if there is 2 letters? ie "ab" and you wanted to find coordinate for each letter?


use another for loop and a substring function?

Comment: Not exactly, you would need another FOR loop, but you can just use the Chars(index) property. 'Matrix(i, y).Chars(z) = "a"'. But if you're using a string there are other functions you can also access like "IndexOf()" which will bring you the index of only the first occurence of a character and hence you would not need to write another FOR loop. 'z = Matrix(i, y).IndexOf("a")'

Comment: Ok, let me try to explain it again. Using "ab" instead of "a" automatically states that you're declaring a string, instead of just a char (string is basically just another array of chars). so your declaration should look like:
Dim Matrix As String(,) = {{"ab", "bc", "cd", "de", "ef"}, {"ab", "bc", "cd", "de", "ef"} .

Comment: As string is just another array of char, that declaration basically means that you have a three-dimensional array of char. However, in VB.NET there a some additional functions added to the string class for easier modification. Furthermore, you can't access chars from a string quite as you would from an array of char, you need to use the supplied function like ".Chars(index)" as I've mentioned before. I hope this clears up the confusion :)